# ANT passing all command line properties to <java>

Tags: ant, properties, overriding

I have a got a ANT build system which invokes builds on different projects using following macro;

```
    <macrodef name="buildComponent">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="dir"/>
    <attribute name="antTarget"/>
    <attribute name="antCommonDistDir" />
    <sequential>
        <available property="build.xml.exists.@{dir}" file="@{dir}/build.xml" />
        <if>
            <equals arg1="${build.xml.exists.@{dir}}" arg2="true" />
            <then>
                <java   classname="org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher"
                        fork="true"
                        failonerror="true"
                        dir="@{dir}"
                        timeout="4000000"
                        output="${common.build.dir}/log/@{name}.log"
                        taskname="startAnt"  >
                    <jvmarg value="-Dant.home=${ant.home}"/>
                    <classpath>
                        <pathelement location="${ant.home}/lib/ant-launcher.jar"/>
                    </classpath>
                    <arg value="-Dbasedir=@{dir}"/>
                    <arg value="@{antTarget}"/>
                    <arg value="-Dprop1=${prop1}" />

                    <syspropertyset refid="project.common.properties" />
                    <sysproperty key="common.dist.dir.os" value="@{antCommonDistDir}" />
                </java>
            </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

I would like to override properties form command line but the problem is that these properties are not being passed by  task and my subsequent build uses the default values. For example I am executing the build as follows;

```
ant dist -Dprop1=override.prop1 -Dprop2=override.prop2 -Dprop3=override.prop3
```

As you see currently the only option for me to pass these overridden values from command line for **prop2** and **prop3** is add `<arg />` under `<java />` task for each property passed like I have done for 'prop1' which works but not desirable. Is there anyway I can access all properties passed to ANT and simply pass them as is to `<java />` task?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`echoproperties`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) task to save all current Ant properties to a file, and then pass that file to the `java` task to be loaded by the subproject.

```
<echoproperties destfile="my.properties"/>
```

Having said this, a better solution instead of executing the `java` command to invoke another Ant build, you can simply call the [`ant`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task which will build your subproject and automatically *inherit all properties* from the parent project:

```
<available property="build.xml.exists.@{dir}" file="@{dir}/build.xml" />
<if>
    <equals arg1="${build.xml.exists.@{dir}}" arg2="true" />
    <then>
        <ant antfile="@{dir}/build.xml" target="@{antTarget}"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any thing which can do this directly. So I ended up writing a javascript and populated a ant property to parse command line options which was stored in env variable and passed it to `<java />` task as `<arg line="${command.line.properties}" />`. Remember to use `<arg line=""` /> as it trim out all extra spaces etc before invoking a task.